# Java Regex repetition (Dice notation parsing)

Tags: java, regex

I'm using regexp to parse a string of a certain syntax.

```
Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(d)(\\d+)(([\\+\\-\\*\\/])(\\d+))*"); // The regexp pattern
```

I want this to match strings like:

```
2d6
4d4+1
2d12*2-1
```

The problem is, it also matches strings that end on a x-*/ such as:

```
3d4-
```

Comment: Are you using Matcher#find or Matcher#matches to apply your pattern against your input? The former matches part of your input, the latter matches against the whole of your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regex `(\d+)(d)(\d+)(([-+*/])(\d+))`

but 2d12x2-1 would not be match, x is not exist in your regex, and you don't say about it anything, for include `x` change regex to `(\d+)(d)([\dx]+)(([\+\-\*\/])(\d+))`

Edit:

may be you need anchor? set `^` and `$` in your regex

```
Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)(d)(\\d+)(([-+*/])(\\d+))*$");
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a * last to allow repetition of the last part? Other than that, isn't that the same pattern i already have?